# Ruby hash access via symbol not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

created a controller spec that looks like this
require 'spec_helper'

```
describe UsersController do
  it "redirects to user and creates cookie" do
    post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
    expect(response.cookies[:remember_token]).to eq(User.last.remember_token)
    response.should redirect_to User.last
  end
end
```

this doesn't work. The cookie is nil.

however response.cookies['remember_token'])
works fine i.e. the cookie is found.

I was under the impression that the symbol would 'convert' to the string representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for a HashWithIndifferentAccess, which is a Rails construct.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html

Normal Ruby hashes do not equate string keys and symbol keys with each other.

Comment: The issue with this when I set the value I use a symbol not a string...
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = ....
so I would have expected to get it out with a symbol as well?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you assigned like this `cookies['remember_token'] = 'some value'` but it should return 'some value' for each case